# dotnet publish multipe csproj in one time

Tags: c#, .net, publish, csproj

I have a solution that contains multiple projects like :

```
Solution.Sln
---> Authentication (folder)
-------> API.csproj
-------> Service.csproj
-------> Entity.csproj
-------> Others.csproj
---> Common (folder)
---> Finance (folder)
-------> API.csproj
-------> Service.csproj
-------> Entity.csproj
-------> Others.csproj
---> Others (folder)
-------> API.csproj
-------> Service.csproj
-------> Entity.csproj
-------> Others.csproj
```

And i want to write a specific dotnet publish command to publish only Authentication folder that contains projects for an IIS website.
Is there any solution ?

Comment: Is this _.NET Core?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dotnet publish <Path to your .csproj>`. It will build and publish only the specified project and projects it depends on.

Comment: Assuming OP is talking about .NET Core.  Otherwise one might need to use `msbuild`